# How to sort the segments c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11

I have the vector of Edges. I need to sort those edges by y-coordinate of the point of crossing vertical line x==(a+b)/2 and those edges. The problem is the that a and b are not constant and they have to change from one array of edgges to another one. How can I sent the a and b parameters to the comparator?

```
struct vertex
{

   double x,y;

    bool operator==(const vertex &o)const {
        return x == o.x && y == o.y;
    }

    bool operator<(const vertex &o) const{
        return x < o.x || (x == o.x && y < o.y);
    }

};
typedef vector<vertex> vertList;
typedef vector <pair<vertex,vertex>> Edge;
```

Comment: By edge do you mean a line with no start and end point? Otherwise how do you know that the edge and vertical line x==(a+b)/2 has intersection?

Comment: I mean <pair<vertex,vertex>>. First element of pair is start point and the second  one is the finish point. All edges has the intersections. All I need is just calculate the y-coordinate and sort the edges by them.

Comment: I think you can make a lambda function that capture a and b

Comment: By the a and b parameters do you mean o.x and o.y ? right?

Comment: I need to find the point of intersection 1 vertical line(x=(a+b)/2) and segment, which represented like a pair<vertex,vertex>

Answer (score 2):

You can define a comparator class that takes `a` and `b` as constructor arguments:

```
struct EdgeComparator {
    int a;
    int b;

    EdgeComparator(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}

    bool operator<(const Edge& lhs, const Edge& rhs) const {
        // You can compare lhs and rhs using a and b here
    }
};
```

and later pass its instance to the sort function:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), EdgeComparator(some_value_of_a, some_value_of_b));
```